# Android configuration file, can I access it to detect the fontScale at start up?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm aware I can override OnConfigurationChanged() to detect when the fontScale has changed however, I'd like to know at boot up if the configuration file is available for MainActivity to access to see if at run time the fontScale is set to a value other than normal e.g. 1.15 (Large)

Comment: Do you need change the `fontScale` when you app start up?

Comment: No, I'd simply like to know what the fontScale is so I can determine other aspects of the UI 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android configuration file, can I access it to detect the fontScale at start up?

The answer is Yes, you could change the `FontScale` to a value other than normal. For example, change the  `FontScale` when your application start up:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    initFontScale();
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    ...
}

private void initFontScale()
{
    Configuration configuration = Resources.Configuration;
    configuration.FontScale = (float)1.45;
    //0.85, 1 standard, 1.15 bigger, 1.3, 1.45

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * metrics.Density;

    // DEPRECATED BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    // Beter use:
    BaseContext.ApplicationContext.CreateConfigurationContext(configuration);
    BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(metrics);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your help 

Comment: @FullEnglish, if this can help you, please mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: All done, I had to refer to help on how to accept the answer haha.  It wasn't obvious at first :)

Comment: @FullEnglish, happy coding. :)

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I agree, exactly what I was looking for. Quick Question, intellisense says Resources.UpdateConfiguration is deprecated(obsolete). Code still works, but wondering if you know what the updated method to do the same thing is? If they've even updated anything.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT  Thank You! This works as expected.  As Tim was saying Resources.UpdateConfiguration() is depreciated.  Do you know what we should be using to do the same?